# Prometheus Query to aggregate metrics by certain label values

Tags: prometheus

I have my metrics exposed by Prometheus as:

```
custom_metric{label1="abc", label2="xyz"} num1
custom_metric{label1="def", label2="uvw"} num2
custom_metric{label1="ghi", label2="rst"} num3
custom_metric{label1="jkl", label2="opq"} num4
```

I want to query the metric such that I get sum of metric for `label1="abc"`, `label1="def"` and `label1="jkl"`.

I expect the result after querying to be something on lines of `custom_metric_groupped (num1 + num2 + num4)`.

Another thing, in my use case, the number of specific label values can vary. So, it might be the case that in future I might want to only take the sum for `label1="def"` and `label1="jkl"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
sum(custom_metric{label1=~"abc|def|jkl"})
```

It works in the following way:

1. It selects time series matching label selector `custom_metric{label1=~"abc|def|jkl"}` - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). Note that the required values for the `label1` are enumerated in the regexp filter with `|` delimiter.
2. It sums values for the selected time series individually per each requested timestamp (aka point on the graph) via [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) aggregate function.